# how to separate the sculpting layer as a different object in blender?

Tags: texturing, objects, transparency, sculpting, layers

i have sculpted a dragon now i have applied some texture/alpha like curly horns,skins using brush on whole body of a dragon, now i want that extra texture which i applied as a different object or layer. so that i can independently edit both of them. if i can hide the texture , i want to see only original dragon body or vice versa. that's what[image] i want.

Comment: There aren't sculpting layers in Blender like those in ZBrush, probably yet. You can workaround this by using shapekeys (setting value of key to 1, then sculpting), but that should be done before sculpting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have applied these directly to your base mesh you will not be able to separate them.  The closest you can get to what you want is to use the multires modifier which will allow you to sculpt different levels of detail at different resolutions.